# Integrating $e^x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm wondering if there are any rules to integrate $e^x$? For example $e^{-0.05x}$. Can I use the reversed chain rule, u-sub or something to easily integrate most examples of $e^x$?

Comment: Perhaps I should have called this $e^{kx}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Given $\lambda \in \Bbb R$, differentiate $x\mapsto \dfrac{e^{\lambda x}}{\lambda} $.

More generally, given a function $f$ such that there exists $F$ with the property that $F'=f$, to obtain an antiderivative of $(f\circ u)u'$ where $u$ is some differentiable function such that the composition makes sense, differentiate $F\circ u$: $(F\circ u)'=(F'\circ u)u'=(f\circ u)u'$.

Comment: So if I have a function of the form $e^{kx}$ to be integrated I can simply divide by $k$?

Comment: To obtain an antiderivative of $x\mapsto e^{\lambda x}$ you divide the original function by $\lambda$, yes. But this only works because the derivative of $x\mapsto \lambda x$ is $x\mapsto \lambda$. In this example $u(x)=\lambda x$.

Comment: Thank you. That's all I'm looking for, for now. Will accept answer when it opens up.

Comment: @Paze Do not rush to accept my answer. It's good that you accept answers, but give it time. If I may suggest so, accept an answer to this question tomorrow. The point being that what you feellike are better answers may come up.

Comment: Okay, I will do that from now on.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( e^{f(x)} + k\right) = e^{f(x)}f'(x) \quad \text{ implies } \quad \int e^{f(x)}f'(x)~dx = e^{f(x)} + k$$

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{a^{f(x)}}{\log a} + k\right) = a^{f(x)}f'(x)\quad \text{ implies } \quad \int a^{f(x)} f'(x)~dx = \frac{a^{f(x)}}{\log a} + k$$